# How to make a simple GitLab Ci/CD gitlab-ci.yml file to build an Angular project?

Tags: angular, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

This is for an Angular project I have.

The project itself builds and runs just fine. I have just been struggling with trying to figure out how to make my 1st CI/CD pipeline process **gitlab-ci.yml** file. This has been going on for months.

How the heck is this to be setup because I cannot find a basic example that just works.

```
image: node:14.17.0

stages:            # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - setup
  - build
  - cleanup

.pre:
  stage: setup,
  script:
    - mkdir -p dist
    - npm install -g @angular/cli@12.2.16
    - npm install  # or `npm install` or whatever you use to install deps
    - npm start
    - npm --version
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules
    policy: pull

build-job:
  stage: build
  script:          # ... your other build steps here
    - npm run build_def_mysetup
    - ls /builds
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules
    policy: pull
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/

.post:
  stage: cleanup
  script:
    - echo "cleanup called"
```

The goal right now for this is to

1. Install needed node_modules for the build
2. Build the Angular application
3. Eventually if build fails, notify via email the developer who last pushed the build
4. Eventually if build pass - do nothing
5. Eventually if build pass - Run unit tests
6. Eventually if build pass and branch has release in name - tag the branch

I say eventually because I cannot get #1 to work

Comment: what is the goal of the pipeline? you do not want to run ```npm start``` inside the pipeline. What you may be aiming for is to build the angular project, and then to dockerize it and create an image. Is that right?

Comment: I'll update the OP with my goal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, i had a quick glance at your pipeline and tried it on an angular project.
First, by following the **gitlab-ci** documentation, you should not mix stages, with `.pre` and `.post`. please take a look at [Gitlab CI stages](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#stages), in this matter.

Next, for the matter of artifacts, you do not need to specifically set path to artifacts, as they are kept between subsequent stages.

Now for the pipeline

-

1. **Install dependencies - node_modules**

   - simply install npm packages

   ```
   stage: install_dependencies
   image: node:14
   script:
   - npm install
   ```
2. **Install angular**

   - the script may be varying, but the base idea is kept

   ```yaml
   stage: install_angular
   image: node:14
   script:
   - npm install -D typescript @angular/cli @angular/compiler
   ```
3. **Build angular app**

   ```yaml
   stage: build
   image: node:14
   script:
   - npm run build
   ```
4. **Notify if the build fails**

   - This is a default behaviour of gitlab, when you run a pipeline and it fails, then you receive an email with the status, see image [image: pipeline failed]
5. Run unit tests + release

   - the same steps as previous steps

The full pipeline would look something like this (its a trivial example, it can be merged into one stage)

```yaml
image: node:14.17.0

stages:            # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
 - install_dependencies
 - install_angular
 - build
 

install_dep:
  stage: install_dependencies
  image: node:14
  script:
  - npm install

install_ang:
  stage: install_angular
  image: node:14
  script:
 - npm install -D typescript @angular/cli @angular/compiler

build_ang:
  stage: build
  image: node:14
  script:
  - npm run build
```

Comment: Question: Is the command option "-D" being used because -g is not viable in the CI/CD realm?

Comment: So between the install node, install angular and build project it is not required to use the 'artifacts: path:' dist or node_modules. GitLab CI/CD knows the information..... But if I'm doing TEST after the build won't I need to specify on the build job to make use of the 'artifacts: path:' at that point?

Comment: you can skip the parameter as it was only for showcase, -g would work as well as the runtime of the pipeline is a normal linux environment

Comment: artifacts are preserved between stages. but for jobs, you could add ```needs``` (refer to documentation). however, in your scenario, you wouldnt need it

Comment: In your above example, which does work for me :), the image: node:14 is that a shorthand for image: name:... ? I cannot find the exact format you have in the documentation.

Comment: well it is the same structure as docker images in compose files, so in this scenario
```image: node:14``` is docker.io/library/node:14

Comment: The naming now makes more sense and the layout of the build script as I've been doing a lot of training in Docker this past week. I had no prior exposure to Docker when I created this ticket.

Answer (score 1):

This is what my current file has. I needed the artifact in here otherwise ng would not work.

```
image: node:14.17.0 # This is the container for our Docker we will build in

cache:
  paths:
    - dist/
    - node_modules/

stages:            # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - install_dependencies
  - install_angular
  - build

install_dep:
  stage: install_dependencies
  image: node:14
  script: # Execute script commands just as you would on terminal command line
    - echo $CI_PROJECT_DIR
    - npm install
    - echo npm --version

  artifacts: # This is required for other stage to have access to what gets created
    paths:
      - node_modules/

install_ang:
  stage: install_angular
  image: node:14
  script:
    - npm install -D typescript @angular/cli@12.2.16 @angular/compiler@12.2.16
# Possible that the -D is optional could use -g or none

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm run build_def_mybuild # this is defined in angular.json
    - ls dist/
```

This is as far as I"ve made it. I may need the following for doing tests.

```
  artifacts: # This is required for other stage to have access to what gets created
    paths:
      - dist/
```